# openLDAP TLS using only IP addresses

Tags: linux, openldap

Basically the problem is this: I am setting up an openLDAP server on a CentOS 6.3 and an openLDAP client on Ubuntu 11.04. The problem is, I don't know how to set-up a nameservice for the openLDAP server. Most of the guides I've found make use of a URL which requires a naming service. Is there a way to make use of IP addresses on the URIs for the ldap.conf files in both the client and the server? If yes, how is it done? If not, a guide for setting up a naming service will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

kinda obvious question:
if its only two systems, can you define the hostnames of both server & client in /etc/hosts on each machine?

and if you are looking into more of a domain controller with DNS capabilities etc. 
[Free IPA](http://freeipa.org/page/About) is probably a better fit.